# What is an operator norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, definition, normed-spaces

I came across this symbol where they are mentioning operator norms. I am not sure how it is different from the Frobenius norm. It was something like this:

$|||\Omega-\hat{\Omega} |||_2$ where $\hat{\Omega}$ is the estimate.

Comment: See 
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm

Answer (score 1):

The operator norm of an operator is

$$\|A\| = \sup\left\{ \frac {\|Ab\|}{\|b\|} : b \neq 0 \right\}$$

**Explanation:** The term $\frac {\|Ab\|}{\|b\|}$ is the factor how much the vector $b$ is stretched by $A$. The operator is bounded, iff there is an upper bound for this stretching factor and the supremum of all possible stretching factors is called *operator norm*.

All operators between finite dimensional vector spaces are bounded and their operator norm is the maximal possible stretching factor of an vector by the action the operator.

The [frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_norm#Frobenius_norm) is another norm for finite dimensional operators. From the definition you can see, that the frobenius norm of a matrix is the [euclidian norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_norm#Euclidean_norm) of it. It is not the same as the operator norm but [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_norm#Properties) to it (all norms in a finite dimensional (complex or real) vector spaces are equivalent to each other).